# Leiningen: How to customize the location of the .m2 folder?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I would like to change the location of the .m2 folder where leiningen stores all dependencies (on Linux).

Is it possible to achieve this?

I've checked the source code of the lein.sh script and all environment variables but there's nothing which seems to point to $HOME$/.m2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For leiningen v2:

Put a profiles.clj in ./users/name/.lein (or Linux equivalent) containing the following

```
{:user  {;Location of local repository 
         :local-repo "Drive/Path"
         ;Location of locally installed jars
         ;(that can't be downloaded from public repo's)
         :repositories  {"local" {:url "file://Drive/Path"
                                  :releases {:checksum :ignore}}}}}
```

This user profile is merged with ALL project profiles during lein execution.

A good place to find information like this is the [annotated sample profile](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj) on lein's github.

Comment: I wanted to change my .m2 folder from C:/ to D:/. Added a profiles.clj in the .lein folder as directed above. lein-deps fails with this msg:
_Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.someproject-1.1-SNAPSHOT
This could be due to a typo in :dependencies, file system permissions, or network issues.
If you are behind a proxy, try setting the 'http_proxy' environment variable._
The project.clj of that project has this:
`:repositories [["private" {:url "s3p://myfire/jars/"
:sign-releases false
:username :env :passphrase :env}]]`

Comment: Is it possible that the :repositories of the profiles.clj is overriding the :repositories of project.clj, and since the project has to look for s3 jars, it is failing.
Should the :repositories of project.clj be a {map} and not [vec] ?
If I add [:offline? true](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L153) in the project.clj it succeeds without a .m2 folder in D: or C:.
without the profiles.clj it succeeds lein-deps succeeds with .m2 created in C:
PLEASE HELP !!!